# How to display rgb hex colors on terminal using python?

Tags: linux, terminal, python, colors, ansi

Using ANSI escape sequence, I can change the color of text that python prints. The example below prints "Hi World" in light blue.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
print(f'\033[38;5;117mHi World')
```

While this works I am limited to just 256 colors. Are there any terminals or extensions that allow me to print colors in hex triplets `#000000-#FFFFFF` using python?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are, but not all terminals support it, some do it differently than others, you need to figure out what your terminal's capabilities are... In other words: it's possible, but you don't want to do it yourself.

The standard way of doing it is hence using a library, in the Python casr that would probably be [Rich](https://github.com/Textualize/rich) or [Textual](https://github.com/Textualize/textual), depending on whether you just want pretty colorful text or also prompts, buttons, tables etc.